# c# - What happens in memory when creating objects?

Tags: c#, memory

I have the following code:

```
Student s = new Student();
Student s2 = s;
s2 = new Student();
s = s2;
```

What happens in memory during each step of the code?

Comment: What research have you done so far? Is `Student` a class or a struct?

Comment: @JonSkeet It's a class. I know what happens in the first step but I can't seem to grasp what happens afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the "Student" type is a reference type (class), and not a value type (struct):

```
Student s = new Student();
```

Memory for a new Student object is allocated, and a new reference "s" is created and set to refer to the new memory.

```
Student s2 = s;
```

A new reference "s2" is created and set to refer to the same object and memory as "s". No new object is created, and only enough memory is allocated to account for the reference.

```
s2 = new Student();
```

Memory for a new Student object is allocated. The "s2" reference is changed to refer to this new object. "s" still refers to the object created previously.

```
s = s2;
```

"s" is changed to refer to the object and memory created on the prior line. No new memory is allocated or released. However, there is now nothing referring the original object created on the first line. That object is no longer rooted. The next time the garbage collector runs, the object will be eligible for collection.

Answer (score 2):

Considering  `Student` is a `class`:

```
1. Student s = new Student();
```

An object is created in Managed Memory and its reference is assigned to `s`

```
2. Student s2 = s;
```

Another reference `s2` is created which points to the same instance as of `s`.

```
3. s2 = new Student();
```

`s2` is assigned a new instance of `Student` from managed memory.

```
4. s = s2;
```

`s` now points to the same instance as `s2`. So both `s` and `s2` points to the same instance, and the previous instance created in step 1 is eligible for garbage collection.

You should read the following articles by Eric Lippert.

1. [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/)
2. [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part Two](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two/)